# window.getComputedStyle Not working below the fold

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use `window.getComputedStyle` to get the elements the mouse hover info. More specifically the cursor type ( but not relevant)

The issue is that for some reason it returns an error when hovering the elements below the fold

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.`

```js
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {


  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY)))


});
```

```css
div{
padding: 100px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Item here
</div>
<div>
  Item here
</div>
<div>
  Item here
</div>
<div>
  Item here
</div>
<div>
  Item here
</div>
<div>
  Item here
</div>
<div>
  Item here
</div>
<div>
  Item here
</div>
```

Comment: If the mouse isn't over an element, there's no element to get the style of. `document.elementFromPoint(e.pageX, e.pageY)` returns the `Window` object rather than an element.

Comment: I get that. But I have 8 `divs` and when hover the above the fold ones it returns the object with the element styles. When I hover the ones below the error.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the fold. But clearly the problem is with the return value of `document.elementFromPoint()`. It's not a one of the divs.

Comment: I only get the error if I scroll down and hover over the divs that initially was below the fold (not visible on the viewport when loaded)

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `mouseenter` to get the element that the mouse moves into?

Comment: I am trying to get the cursor type of the element the mouse is hovering. I have a custom cursor and it changes depending on it. Ie. if is `grab`, `pointer`, etc.

Comment: So? The cursor normally changes when you move into a different element. So the `mouseenter` event will be triggered, and then you can use `event.target` to get that element and get its computed style.

Comment: Okay, but I'd need to set a eventListener to all elements. Well, maybe I can do it only on `<a>` and the slider I have that has the `grab` cursor type. Let me give it a try.

Comment: No, you can put the event listener on `window`, it will be triggered for all descendants.

Comment: Ah good to know. However I might only apply to the few elements I need it. Might be better for performance. I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks for helping on the brainstorm :)